# larger size db export from rackspace

Tags: mysql, database, amazon-web-services, rackspace

I am planing to migrate my Db from rackspace to AWS. The current db has around 50GB of size.
So how can i export this Db from rackspace without downtime.Or any other solutions like direct migration from rackspace to AWS RDS

Comment: You really need to start by understanding what AWS provides from an import perspective and then work back from there. Incidentally I imagine your database could be made a lot smaller when exported and then encrypted & compressed, but that will depend on the content (e.g. whether there is a lot of digital media in there). Basically we don't have enough information to advise, I really would start by finding out what AWS has to offer.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon provides [multiple options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/MySQL.Procedural.Importing.Other.html) in the RDS docs. Have you read them?

My preference would be to set up replication between your Rackspace instance and a new RDS instance. This will minimize your downtime: when you're ready you shut down your applications, reconfigure them to use the new database, and you're done.

I recommend planning for at least three attempts, since replication can be tricky the first time you set it up. Even if you get the replication right on the first try, I *strongly* suggest that you bring up a test environment and do a complete regression test of your app, before *repeating* the replication for your production cutover.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can easily achieve migration without any outage using DMS services given by Amazon. I used DMS for migration from Company Hosted Environment to RDS.